# When using JTable with cell selection, selecting a cell removes whole selection

Tags: java, jtable

I have a table where you can select specific cells.
When you select row 1 and 2 for first column by using Ctrl-click, and then you remove selection on one of the rows, the other row also get de-selected:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Test");
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        DefaultTableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{new Object[]{1,"A"},new Object[]{2, "B"},new Object[]{3, "C"}}, new Object[]{"Test", "Test2"});
        table.setModel(tm);
        jf.setSize(300, 400);
        jf.getContentPane().add(table);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
```

[image: Initial]

Ctrl + Click on Test/2:

[image: Result]

I expected:

[image: Expected value]

From what i understand of the Swing code, the problem is that the column selection model has a code that does something like: if col = 0 selected, remove selection altogether. So when the table re-rendered, there's no column selection and whole selection gets cleared.

Is there a way to prevent whole deselection without recoding the whole DefaultSelectionModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by keeping track of the last selected column and having a selection listener that checks if selected row count is > 0, then select the lastly selected column, not perfect mayhaps but it seems to work fine